# java swing : Notifying clients on server restart or shutdown

Tags: java, client-server

**Background:**

I have written a java swing based client server application. The server is a spring container and has a bunch of services. The server-client communicate through serialized objects over sockets. The server spawns a new thread for each client session and maintains a map of the sessions over the period of communication.

I am adding a shutdown hook to the JVM

In my GUI, i have a "Stop Server" button which removes user sessions and cleans up .

**Problem:** This all works fine, but now I would like to let the clients known if the server is restarting or stopped. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a method to receive replies from the server. Let that method run in a separate thread and permanently waiting in a loop for messages from the server. When the server stops, the connection is closed, and the receiving method gets an exception.

Answer (score 1):

As [Alexei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206301/alexei-kaigorodov) stated, you could wait for the client to throw an exception, and automatically say that it's because the server is shutting down or has stopped. However, this may not be the best way to go about it unless you know for sure that will be the only error your server will ever have.

I recommend using sending all the clients a certain messages that tells the client the server is being stopped on purpose. When the clients receive that certain message, they can close their sockets. Refer to Sun's example of the [Knock Knock Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).